# How do I identify which M1 Mac model that the iOS app is running on?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-m1

I am running my iOS app on M1 based Macs without modifying anything (Catalyst etc). I know that when I run the app, the system treats it as if it is being played on iPad.

When I run these lines of code:

```
print("LOG: \(ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac)")
print("LOG: \(ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString)")
print("LOG: \(UIDevice.current.model)")
print("LOG: \(UIDevice.current.systemVersion)")
var size = 0
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
var machine = [CChar](repeatElement(0, count: Int(size)))
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
print("LOG: \(String(cString: machine))")
```

These get printed if I choose `My Mac (Designed for iPad)` as the target:

```
LOG: true
LOG: Version 15.7 (Build 21G115)
LOG: iPad
LOG: 15.7
LOG: iPad8,6
```

These get printed if I choose `iPhone 14 Pro` simulator as the target:

```
LOG: false
LOG: Version 16.0 (Build 20A360)
LOG: iPhone
LOG: 16.0
LOG: arm64
```

I would like to determine current device model when the app is running on M1 macs to feed analytics accurately.

Is this possible? As per my investigation, I could not find anything beyond that `ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac` flag, is this correct?